# Typescript, Type error null with Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an error with `error` on `defaultState` const:

```
interface AuthState<T = any> {
  auth: T;
  error: null | Error;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const defaultState: { auth: null | AuthState } = {
  auth: null,
  error: null, // Here I got the error
  loading: false
};
```

The error is:

```
TS2322: Type '{ auth: null; error: null; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ auth: AuthState<any> | null; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'error' does not exist in type '{ auth: AuthState<any> | null; }'.
```

I can't get everything ok with types, any hint here?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? here you're saying that `defaultState` is an object with just one property named `auth` which can be either of type `AuthState` or null. but you're adding properties like `loading` and `error` to your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
interface AuthState<T = any> {
  auth: T;
  error: null | Error;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const defaultState: { auth: null } | AuthState = {
  auth: null,
  error: null, // Here I got the error
  loading: false
};
```

What you did before was saying that `auth` is either `null` or `AuthState`. But I guess what you wanted to say was: `defaultState` is either `{ auth: null }` or `AuthState`.